# How to force TLS 1.3 version in Python

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, serversocket

I have made Python sockets and am working on server and client Python files respectively. Some codes on the server.py are as below.(Code related to TLS connection)

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_3)
```

When I checked the communication on the wire shark, I always did TLS1.2, so I proceeded with some measures to enforce TLS1.3

```
#context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2 # optional
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2

context.set_ciphers('AES256+ECDH:AES256+EDH') #original
```

Despite my efforts to enforce TLS1.3, it still continues to communicate with TLS1.2.

```
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1)    #TRUE
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_1)  #TRUE
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_2)  #TRUE
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_3)  #TRUE
```

Like this, I tried to print out to check if ssl supports each version of TLS, but all of them printed "True".

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mycert.pem -keyout mycert.pem
```

The command I used to generate the certificate is as above.

My Openssl version is also 1.1.1(which supports TLS 1.3). Everything seems fine, but I wonder why it still communicates with TLS 1.2. I'd like to know the option to keep the TLS 1.3 connection.
[image]

Comment: `ssl.HAS_TLSv1` and similar are documented as _"Whether the OpenSSL library has built-in support for the TLS 1.0 protocol."_ It is a constant describing an installed library and cannot be changed. Are you actually connecting to the TLS server?

Comment: @VPfB When I checked 3handshaking with WireShark, I checked to communicate TLS1.2 version. Are there any special options for activating TLS 1.3?

Comment: I don't know all details, but please post the exact version of your OpenSSL library and the Python version. Lots of stuff depends on versions. Check also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.minimum_version

Comment: @VPfB My python version is 3.9.1 and Openssl is 1.1.1k! Thank you for your help btw

Comment: @VPfB I'm now using the code of [link](https://asecuritysite.com/subjects/chapter107) this.

Comment: I tried the server code from the link. I was connecting with `openssl s_client -connect ....` It worked for me as expected and I could not reproduce the problem (TLS 1.2 connection accepted even if disabled with `ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2`). When TLS <= 1.2 was disabled  on the server side, the client could connect with 1.3, but not with the `-no_tls1_3` option. When TLS <=1.1 was disabled on the server, the client could connect with 1.2 (1.3 was still disabled on the client side). Python 3.9.5 on Linux. Openssl 1.1.1k (same version).

Comment: Maybe the problem is not what it seems: please read: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55752/why-does-wireshark-show-version-tls-1-2-here-instead-of-tls-1-3

Comment: @VPfB Oh dear, I've been working on this all day and you've cleared the question. I am very happy that the question has been resolved. Thank you so much for helping me like it's your job. If there's a little difference, I'm a Windows version.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped. Anyway I would just verify the TLS version with another tool before calling the problem resolved.

Comment: @EmmaLim If I remember correctly for compatibility reasons an TLS 1.3. handshake always uses TLS.1.2 in the main version info field. You have to check the handshake extensions to get the real version -> check the "Client Hello" message in detail. This workaround was necessary as too many "middle-Boxes" on the internet could not handle connections with TLS1.3 in the header.

Comment: @Robert Oh what you just said seems to be somewhat the same as what commented on the above link. Even with TLS1.3, there seems to be a significant amount of forcing with TLS1.2. It helped a lot.

Comment: @VPfB That was my mistake. I edited my comment, THX again!